# Uploading files to directory

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I now have a php file which uploads files to my web server. Currently it will upload files such as jpg files, however whenever I try to upload an excel or a word file (which is to be honest, what I need) it doesn't render my code and just says 'invalid file'. I get no errors as it only echos the last line. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$target_path = "uploads/"; 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);  

//$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
//$temp = $target_path . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
//$extension = end($temp);


if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']).  
        " has been uploaded"; 
    }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>upload</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: a print_r($_FILES["file"]) would be useful rather than invalid file.

Comment: your code is working just increase upload limit from 20000 or upload small image

Comment: You are overwriting `$target_path` with `$target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);`. $_FILES will be empty when no file is uploaded so an error will be triggered. Also, for detecting extension I prefer `pathinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. You are getting 'invalid file' message because wither your filesize>= 20000 or your file type does not match with your filters. just increase the filesize in your php  code and make sure your are only uploading "gif", "jpeg", "jpg" or  "png" files.

Comment: I got it working by avoiding the array method (bad practice yes I know) however all I want at the moment is it working. However I cannot now upload word files or anything as such just the jpegs etc... any ideas? I'll edit my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your ms-word .doc files will load perfectly with your code. However if you are trying to upload .docx files (i.e default files of ms-word 2007 onwards) then your code will not work.
To make it work use..
 "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" 
    in addition to 
 "application/msword"

Also in your code change

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"]))

```
                to
```

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))

```
                   Happy computing
```

Comment: Thanks Bobby! I'll try that once I complete this report on design thinking and challenges and get back to you. I love programming at times :/